# Modify Dictionary Value is possible.What is the right approach?

Tags: c#

I have dictionary that is populated and I have no control of.

I need to modify the value how can I do that?

I have put a noddy example together to explain the problem

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Dictionary<Customer, int> CustomerOrderDictionary = new Dictionary<Customer, int>();

        CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, FullName = "Jo Bloogs" },3);

        CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, FullName = "Rob Smith" },5);

        //now I decide to increase the quantity but cannot do the below as value has no setter

        foreach (var pair in CustomerOrderDictionary)
        {
            if(pair.Key.Id==1)
            {
                pair.Value = 4;///ERROR HERE
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you work out which keys need modifying *first*, and then iterate over those modifications. Otherwise you'll end up modifying a collection while you're iterating over it, which will throw an exception. So for example:

```
// The ToList() call here is important, so that we evaluate all of the query
// *before* we start modifying the dictionary
var keysToModify = CustomerOrderDictionary.Keys
                                          .Where(k => k.Id == 1)
                                          .ToList();
foreach (var key in keysToModify)
{
    CustomerOrderDictionary[key] = 4;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot that worked.I will try to see if that works with the real code.thanks

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that pair is typed to `KeyValuePair` which is a readonly object and can't be modified.  Additionally the `KeyValuePair` collection is a way of viewing the contents of the dictionary (not changing it).

What you want to do here is just modify the dictionary directly.  The `Key` in the `KeyValuePair` can be used to update the same entry in the dictionary.

```
if(pair.Key.Id==1) {
  CustomerOrderDictionary[pair.Key] = 4;
}
```

**EDIT**

As Jon pointed out the assignment will invalidate the iterator.  The simplest, but ineffecient route, is to copy the enumerator at the start of the loop.

```
foreach (var pair in CustomerOrderDictionary.ToList())
```

Comment: Except that modifying the dictionary invalidates the iterator :(

Comment: hi,thanks for you reply. tried by doest not work.Are you putting the above in a loop? if not what is pair? sorry for being silly here

Comment: @Jon oh, yes, forgot about that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach

1) Create a new class

```
 // wrapper class to allow me to edit a dictionary
public class IntWrapper
{
    public int OrderCount{ get; set; }
}
```

2) Change this declaration

```
  Dictionary<Customer, IntWrapper> CustomerOrderDictionary = new Dictionary<Customer, IntWrapper>();
```

3) Assign your variable

```
 pair.Value.OrderCount = 4;
```

Comment: Why the negative vote?  It works for me... constructive feedback is appreciated

Comment: I just define a generic `Holder<T>` with a single `Value` field, rather than defining a class to particularly wrap `int`.  Also, you forgot to show how new wrappers should get added to the dictionary.

Comment: One advantage that may be worth mentioning is that when used in free-multi-threaded scenarios, you can use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to guard a dictionary, and only have to acquire a `Writer` lock when you change the dictionary itself.  When working with an item, you may want to acquire a lock on the item, but that won't interfere with others' access to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Customer customer in customers.Keys)
{
    if ( customer.Id == 1 )
        customers[ customer ] = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomerOrderDictionary[1] = 4;
```

Comment: That's wrong, the dictionary's key isn't an int (see my answer..)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that (just the assigning a value part..):

```
CustomerOrderDictionary[new Customer { Id = 1, FullName = "Jo Bloogs" }]=4
```

Notice that "1" is not a key in your dictionary. a `Customer` is, so you'll have to use that.

Notice also that `Customer` Should implement `IEquatable` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your example you're effectively just finding the entry for the `Customer` object with `Id` = 1 and updating the associated value.  In practice, I think that your code will likely be able to obtain a reference to your intended `Customer` object prior to updating the associated value in the dictionary.  If that is the case, then there's no need for a loop.

Below is a very simple example where a loop is not needed because your code already has a reference to the `customer1` variable.  While my example is overly simplified, the concept is that you could potentially obtain a reference to your desired `Customer` object through some means other than iterating over the dictionary.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<Customer, int> CustomerOrderDictionary = new Dictionary<Customer, int>();

        Customer customer1 = new Customer { Id = 1, FullName = "Jo Bloogs" };
        Customer customer2 = new Customer { Id = 2, FullName = "Rob Smith" };

        CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(customer1, 3);

        CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(customer2, 5);

        // you already have a reference to customer1, so just use the accessor on the dictionary to update the value
        CustomerOrderDictionary[customer1]++;
    }
```

If you need to perform some kind of update on multiple `Customer` objects based on some other criteria, then you might need a loop.  The following example assumes that you'll have some collection other than the dictionary that stores your `Customer` objects, and that you can use that collection of `Customer` objects to identify the ones whose associated value in the dictionary need to be updated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // presumably you will have a separate collection of all your Customer objects somewhere
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        Customer customer1 = new Customer { Id = 1, FullName = "Jo Bloogs" };
        Customer customer2 = new Customer { Id = 2, FullName = "Rob Smith" };
        Customer customer3 = new Customer { Id = 3, FullName = "Rob Zombie" };

        customers.Add(customer1);
        customers.Add(customer2);
        customers.Add(customer3);

        Dictionary<Customer, int> CustomerOrderDictionary = new Dictionary<Customer, int>();

        CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(customer1, 3);
        CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(customer2, 5);

        // let's just say that we're going to update the value for any customers whose name starts with "Rob"
        // use the separate list of Customer objects for the iteration,
        // because you would not be allowed to modify the dictionary if you iterate over the dictionary directly
        foreach (var customer in customers.Where(c => c.FullName.StartsWith("Rob")))
        {
            // the dictionary may or may not contain an entry for every Customer in the list, so use TryGetValue
            int value;
            if (CustomerOrderDictionary.TryGetValue(customer, out value))
                // if an entry is found for this customer, then increment the value of that entry by 1
                CustomerOrderDictionary[customer] = value + 1;
            else
                // if there is no entry in the dictionary for this Customer, let's add one just for the heck of it
                CustomerOrderDictionary.Add(customer, 1);
        }
    }
```

If this is not the case and the only source of `Customer` objects that you have available is the dictionary itself, then you'll need to perform some kind of cloning/copying of those objects out to a separate list/array prior to iterating over the dictionary for modification.  See Jon Skeet's answer for this case; he suggests using a `Where` filter on the dictionary's `Keys` property and uses the `ToList` method to create a separate `List<Customer>` instance for the purpose of iteration.