# Dictionary<Key,Value> - key cannot be class?

Tags: c#

I'm using a `Vector3` - contains properties `X`,`Y`,`Z` as a key in a dictionary. Lets say I already added to the dictionary (`myDic`) a `Vector3` with values (0,0,0).

Then I do this:

```
Vector3 vec = new Vector3(0,0,0);
if (!myDic.ContainsKey(vec))
{
    //Should never reach here.
}
```

I also created overload operators for `==` and `!=` for the `Vector3` class.

It reaches there anyways. Is there a problem when using an object like a Vector3 to be the key for a dictionary?

Comment: Why should it never reach there?  Did you ever add that vector to the dictionary?  It doesn't look like it.

Comment: I mentioned that I added it already.

Comment: Did you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are implementing it wrong :)

In short, you need to implement [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): `==` and `!=` are irrelevant here as they are not used.

The reason `==` and `!=` are not used is that they, like all operators, are *non virtual* and the "constraint" for the K in `IDictionary<K,V>` is `object` (not specified, really). Therefore, *only the (virtual) methods valid for all objects* (which includes all sub-types of `object`) such as `Equals` and `GetHashCode` can be used in a polymorphic fashion here.

See [Example of Dictionary collection with custom class as key?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/41fd15a3-6fda-4855-afe5-73498fd1a067) for a working example with test-case.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

You need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` inside your class. The dictionary works on the combination of both, with the first check being the hash and the clincher being `Equals`. Providing a custom implementation for `==` is not going to do anything for your dictionary.

If you are unable or unwilling to override these methods within the class itself, your other option is to implement an `IEqualityComparer<YourClass>` and provide an instance of the implementation in the dictionary constructor. It will be within this implementation that you will provide code for the aforementioned methods.