# How to use custom object as dictionary key?

Tags: c#

I want to create a `Dictionary<Coordinate, Status>`, but the key is always equals to `"Bot.Core.Games.Coordinate"`.

### Classes

**Coordinate**

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

**Status**

```
public class Enums
{
    public enum Status { UNCAPTURED, PLAYER1, PLAYER2, WIN }
}
```

---

### First try

```
Dictionary<Coordinate, Status> Fields { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Coordinate, Status>()
{
    {new Coordinate() { x = 0, y = 0 }, Status.UNCAPTURED}
}
```

### Second try

I did some research and I found this: [Use custom object as Dictionary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999191/use-custom-object-as-dictionary-key) 
So the code now looks like this:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Coordinate coordinate) => coordinate.x.Equals(x) && coordinate.y.Equals(y);
    public bool Equals(object o) => Equals(o as Coordinate);
    public override int GetHashCode() => x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode();
}
```

### Third try

Since none of the previously tried code works I did more research and found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41fd15a3-6fda-4855-afe5-73498fd1a067/example-of-dictionary-collection-with-custom-class-as-key?forum=netfxbcl).
So now the code is:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public class CoordinateEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Coordinate>
    {
        public bool Equals(Coordinate a, Coordinate b) => ((a.x == b.x) & (a.y == b.y));

        public int GetHashCode(Coordinate obj)
        {
            string combined = obj.x + "|" + obj.y;
            return (combined.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
                                                                               
Dictionary<Coordinate, Status> Fields { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Coordinate, Status>(new Coordinate.CoordinateEqualityComparer())
{
     {new Coordinate() { x = 0, y = 0 }, Status.UNCAPTURED}
}
```

The key is always `"Bot.Core.Games.Coordinate"`. How to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't, you are just getting confused about what the debugger tells you.  Override ToString() to make it look better.

Comment: @HansPassant But it also throws a KeyNotFoundException.

Comment: Was `(a.x == b.x) & (a.y == b.y)` supposed to be `(a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y)`?

Comment: Why is `Status` inside another class (`Enums`)?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto: The difference between & and && when operating on boolean operands is that && is short-circuiting while & is not (i.e., the second operand of an & operation will be evaluated even if the the first is false). Who knew!? Eric Lippert pointed this out to me about 5 years ago in a feedback comment on his blog. It's like the difference between And and AndAlso in VB. Thanks again Eric.

Comment: @Flydog57 I know the difference, I was just pointing out what was likely a typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an override in your second try:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt that was the reason the OP had problems - have a look at the comments

Comment: Well, just try it. I had. Without that override it throws `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: This answer could use a bit more explanation. No, I did not down vote.

Comment: Thanks, now working fine, but now I can't save it into a .json file.

Comment: True. Such keys are not json serializable. Only primitives. Remember: dictionaries and objects have the same json representations. A key has to be valid field name (identifier). But you certainly can write custom seriializer for this class as you can simply represent the coordinates in a valid identifier string.

Answer (score 2):

The key is always displayed as `Bot.Core.Games.Coordinate` because in default, the `ToString` method returns the class name and this is the method the debugger calls to display its value. If you override the method like this:

```
public override string ToString() => $"{x} / {y}";
```

It will display its true value.

The problem with your third try was (as was pointed out by Camilo Terevinto and ZorgoZ) your equality comparison - try

```
public override bool Equals(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
{
    return ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y));
}
```

instead

Comment: This answer is also useful.