# Creating a custom Key in a dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create a custom key for a dictionary.

Here is how I create the class

```
public class ImageKey
{
    public int RId;
    public int EId;
    public int LId;

    public ImageKey(int rId, int eId, int lId)
    {
        RId = rId;
        EId = eId;
        LId = lId;
    }


    public bool Equals(ImageKey x, ImageKey y)
    {
        return x.RId == y.RId && x.LId == y.LId &&
              x.EId == y.EId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ImageKey obj)
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + obj.RId.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + obj.EId.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + obj.LId.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

}
```

I use it as a hashset like that

```
HashSet<ImageKey> resourcesId = new HashSet<ImageKey>();
```

and as a Dictionary

```
var enteries = new Dictionary<ImageKey, int>();
```

but this statement fails for ContainsKey when I iterate over and try to see if there is a matched key

```
ImageKey key = new ImageKey(rId, eId, lId);
bool knownId = enteries.ContainsKey(key);
if (!knownId)
{
   enteries.Add(key, new IgaEntry());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: `x.LId == y.Ld` is that a typo? More so, your constructor doesn't make sense.

Comment: I believe you would need to use the `override` keyword for "Equals" and "GetHashCode" for this to work.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yea its a typo

Comment: @AhmedSaleh You need to implement `IEquatable<ImageKey>`

Comment: Your code does not compile. I think you need to modify either the property names used in your constructor or the actual property names in the class. There are no members named 'ResourceId', 'EditionId', and 'LocationId'.

Comment: @RufusL there maybe typos, I will fix them. I just wrote it out of my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You class needs to override `object.Equals`, Implement `IEquatable<T>` interface, or implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and pass it as a keyComparer to Dictionary's constructor.
Also you need to override `GetHashCode` method to avoid unexpected behavior, [make sure you do it right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)

Otherwise, your class will be compared by reference.

[Refer Marc's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key-in-net) for a sample.