# What the best way in typescript to index Map by several object properties?

Tags: typescript

I need something like [Using an object as a generic Dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key) but for TypeScript.

How to implement this using TypeScript?

Comment: Have you tried to do this? You might look at other questions regarding implementing dictionaries in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to implement this using TypeScript?

I've done this in the past : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections#a-sample-on-dictionary